# How can i download imagine on Small Basic app?

Tags: imagedownload, smallbasic

I can't download imagine on small basic . After that, I install Visual Studio but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me this problem:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu2WU.png)

I want to download imagine on Small Basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image can be previously loaded into an ImageList. Here you can see the size of the image and whether the download worked at all.

```
'Imagine = ImageList.LoadImage("https://aka.ms/mz1")
'...("https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1353849")
Imagine1 = ImageList.LoadImage("http://litdev.co.uk/game_images/rubic.png")
Imagine2 = ImageList.LoadImage("http://smallbasic.com/drop/soko/sokocuteff.png")
TextWindow.WriteLine(ImageList.GetHeightOfImage(Imagine1))
TextWindow.WriteLine(ImageList.GetHeightOfImage(Imagine2))
TextWindow.WriteLine(ImageList.GetWidthOfImage(Imagine2))
GraphicsWindow.Height = ImageList.GetHeightOfImage(Imagine2)
GraphicsWindow.Width = ImageList.GetWidthOfImage(Imagine2)

GraphicsWindow.DrawImage(Imagine2,0,0)
GraphicsWindow.DrawImage(Imagine1,100,150)
GraphicsWindow.DrawImage(Imagine1,200,250)
```

**It seems that only http: works and not https:**

[image]